# pydantic Model Inheritance workaround to retyping information?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a model_B that inherits from model_A as seen below:

```
class model_A(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Age: int
    phone: int

class model_B(model_A):
    email: str
    location: str
```

When using my models in code is there a way I can create a model_B without having to retype all the information from model_A? Instead of doing the below is there a way to just add in the email and location and keep all other attributes from model_A?

```
A = model_A(
    Name = "Jon"
    Age = 20
    phone = 123
    
)

B = model_B(
    Name = "Jon"
    Age = 20
    phone = 123
    email = "test@123"
    location = "Earth"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution:

```
A = model_A(
    Name = "Jon"
    Age = 20
    phone = 123
    
)

B = model_B(
    email = "test@123",
    location = "Earth",
    **A.dict()
)
```

to exclude Age:

```
B = model_B(
    email = "test@123",
    location = "Earth",
    **A.dict(exclude={'Age'})
)
```

Comment: And let's imagine that on model_B you what to exclude the Age, how can you accomplish that? @WaketZheng

Comment: You can run this command to see the document: `python -c 'from pydantic import BaseModel;help(BaseModel.dict)'`

Comment: And strongly recommend to follow this code style: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/